# Error installing old tm package in R

Tags: r, rstudio, tm

I'm trying to install a 0.6-2 version of the tm library. I've downloaded the tar.gz file from the [archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/tm/) and in RStudio selected Tools -> Archive -> Package Archive File to install it. I have also installed the latest version of Java and Rtools.

However, I'm getting the following error. Can someone help me fix this please:

> ** libs
>
> *** arch - i386
>
> Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/Users/603666~1/DOCUME~1/R/R-33~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/Users/603666~1/DOCUME~1/R/R-33~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="tm.dll" OBJECTS="copy.o"' had status 127
>
> ERROR: compilation failed for package 'tm'
>   * removing 'C:/Users/603666962/Documents/R/R-3.3.2/library/tm'
>
> Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/Users/603666~1/DOCUME~1/R/R-33~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/Users/603666~1/DOCUME~1/R/R-33~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="tm.dll" OBJECTS="copy.o"' had status 127
>
> ERROR: compilation failed for package 'tm'
>   * removing 'C:/Users/603666962/Documents/R/R-3.3.2/library/tm'
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>     running command '"C:/Users/603666~1/DOCUME~1/R/R-33~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\603666962\Documents\R\R-3.3.2\library" "C:/Users/603666~1/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpug1HRz/downloaded_packages/tm_0.6-2.tar.gz"' had status 1
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘C:/Users/603666~1/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpug1HRz/downloaded_packages/tm_0.6-2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>     running command '"C:/Users/603666~1/DOCUME~1/R/R-33~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\603666962\Documents\R\R-3.3.2\library" "C:/Users/603666~1/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpug1HRz/downloaded_packages/tm_0.6-2.tar.gz"' had status 1
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘C:/Users/603666~1/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpug1HRz/downloaded_packages/tm_0.6-2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was being caused by the RStudio version. I could install the tm package successfully after updating to the latest version of RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I install gfortran and it solved the problem. Install gfortran on your machine and try to install it again.